# Solving a system of linear equations over the field F(2) with python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, finite-field

Is there a way that I can solve a system of linear equations over the field F2(i.e addition and multiplication modulo 2 - the binary field) using python?
I've been trying to search for a useful package for a while but hadn't come up with anything...

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question [solving matrices in finite field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190182/sympy-solving-matrices-in-a-finite-field)?

Answer (score 2):

I created a Python package [galois](https://github.com/mhostetter/galois) that extends NumPy arrays over finite fields. It also supports NumPy linear algebra routines in `np.linalg`.

Here is an example solving a linear system `Ax = b` for `x` in `GF(2)`.

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import galois

In [3]: GF = galois.GF(2)

In [4]: A = GF.Random((4,4)); A
Out[4]: 
GF([[0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 0]], order=2)

In [5]: x_truth = GF([1,0,1,1]); x_truth
Out[5]: GF([1, 0, 1, 1], order=2)

In [6]: b = A @ x_truth; b
Out[6]: GF([0, 0, 1, 1], order=2)

# Solve Ax = b for x
In [7]: x = np.linalg.solve(A, b); x
Out[7]: GF([1, 0, 1, 1], order=2)

# Verify that x is x_truth
In [8]: np.array_equal(x, x_truth)
Out[8]: True
```