# Linear independence of vectors in modular arithmetic mod 2 using Python

Tags: python, svd, modular-arithmetic

I would like to check if there is an easy way to implement a check of linear (in)dependence of vectors but using modular arithmetic mod 2.

For example, suppose you have the following 3 vectors:

1. v1 = (1,1,0);
2. v2 = (0,1,1);
3. v3 = (1,0,1).

If we use scipy.linalg's null_space such that:

```
M = [[1,0,1],
     [1,1,0],
     [0,1,1]]
null_space(M)
```

we get as a result that the 3 vectors are linearly independent, which is obviously true.

However, what I want to check is linear (in)dependence considering modular arithmetic mod 2. In that case, it is easy to check that v3 = v1 + v2 (i.e., the three vectors are linearly dependent).

Is there any way to determine this in Python?

Thank you in advance.

---

UPDATE (02/01/2022): Is there an alternative to doing this with sympy as suggested in one of the answers below? While this solution works for small instances I have noticed (in growing the matrix size) that the code sometimes gets stuck for over 30hours without being able to move on. This is very dependent on the example, which I find fascinating. That is, for a given size while some examples are worked through reasonably quickly (~2hours) others get stuck and the code still hasn't found a solution after 30hours which is less than desirable.! So, is there really no way of doing this with numpy or something like that?

Comment: Maybe this answer has some clues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190182/sympy-solving-matrices-in-a-finite-field

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using `sympy`, adapted from the answer linked by @Lagerbaer.

When finding the nullspace using sympy, you can pass in an argument `iszerofunc`, which specifies what you consider to be zeros in your matrix. In the case of the field of integers mod 2, our zero function is `lambda x: x % 2 == 0`.

You can verify that running the following code outputs a non-zero nullspace.

```
import sympy
M = sympy.Matrix([[1,0,1],
     [1,1,0],
     [0,1,1]])
print(M.nullspace(iszerofunc=lambda x: x % 2 == 0))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this works exactly as I need it to!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one relatively quick and simple implementation of matrix reduction to find a rank mod 2. To clarify, vectors $r_1, ..., r_k$ are linearly independent if and only if the matrix with rows $r_1, ..., r_k$ has rank k.

**Matrix representation.** I like to represent Z_2-matrices as dictionaries of the form `{ row index : set of column indices containing 1 }`. This is not too important, but it is convenient to work with, and it can speed things up considerably if you have sparse matrices.

**The reduction algorithm.** We reduce rows one by one from top to bottom. For each row we try to push the left-most 1 as much to the right as possible by adding previous rows. To this extent, we look at the left-most 1, i.e., the index `min(row)`, and check whether some `other_row` above has the same value `min(row) == min(other_row)`. If it does, we add the `other_row` to `row`. We repeat until we cannot reduce `row` any more. Instead of searching through the rows every time, we store the information in `pivot_inverse`, a dictionary of the form `{min(row) : row}`. At the end, we have a reduced matrix with each non-zero row having a unique pivot -- the rank of the matrix is the number of pivots, equivalently the number of non-zero rows.

```py
def list_to_sparse(M):
    '''Convert list of lists to row sparse matrix representation.'''
    return {row_index : set(index for index,value in enumerate(row) if value)
            for row_index, row in enumerate(M)}

def rank_Z2(M):
    '''Given a Z_2 matrix in row sparse representation, reduce it and return rank.'''
    pivot_inverse = {} # remembers which row has a pivot in a given column
    for row_index in sorted(M): # we reduce rows one by one from top to bottom
        pi = pivot_inverse.get(min(M[row_index], default=-1), -1)
        while M[row_index] and pi!=-1:
            M[row_index]^= M[pi] # add rows mod 2
            pi = pivot_inverse.get(min(M[row_index], default=-1), -1)
        if M[row_index]:
            pivot_inverse[min(M[row_index])] = row_index
        else: # we throw zero rows away
            M.pop(row_index)
    
    return len(pivot_inverse) # rank(M) is the number of pivots
```

**Example.** For the example from the question, we get the following:

```py
M = [[1,0,1],
     [1,1,0],
     [0,1,1]]
M_sparse = list_to_sparse(M)
# now M_sparse = {0: {0, 2}, 1: {0, 1}, 2: {1, 2}}

rank_Z2(M_sparse)
# output: 2
# now M_sparse = {0: {0, 2}, 1: {1, 2}}
```

**Performance.** I am sure things can be sped up if we use better data types for the job, but the run time is decent. On my laptop a random 1000x1000 (very much not sparse) matrix is reduced in ~10 seconds.

```py
import time
import random

rndM = [[random.randint(0,1) for i in range(1000)] for j in range(1000)]
rndM_sparse = list_to_sparse(rndM)
start_time = time.perf_counter()
rank = rank_Z2(rndM_sparse)
print(f"rank: {rank}")
print(f"time: {time.perf_counter() - start_time : .2f} seconds")

# output:
#     rank: 999
#     time:  9.82 seconds
```

We can make `rndM` sparser for example like this

```py
rndM = [[1 - bool(random.randint(0,p)) for i in range(1000)] for j in range(1000)]
```

For `p=100` we have around 10000 ones and we get the rank in around 3 seconds, for p=200 we have around 5000 ones and it takes less than a second .

The code also performs better when the rank is low, so for example non-sparse matrix with the same overall size but shaped 100x10000 gets reduced in about 1.5 seconds.