# Getting the adjugate of matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy

i having some problems in solving the question finding the adjugate of a matrix by given the formula of cofactor matrix

```
c[i][j] = (-1)**(i+j)*m[i][j]
```

where m stand for determinant of matrix.

```
x = np.array([[1,3,5],[-2,-4,-5],[3,6,1]] , dtype = 'int')
```

i only able to do this and don't know how to continue , please help

to find the cofactor i have this hint
def COF(C)
create an empty matrix CO

```
 for row
     for col
         sel_rows = all rows except current row 
         sel_columns = all cols except current col
         MATij = [selected rows and selected columns]
         compute COij
 return CO
```

Comment: Please give the output for this matrix

Answer (score 1):

We can use Boolean indexing to get the submatrices. The required sign change of the determinant is also kept track of, for row and column separately, via the variables `sgn_row` and `sgn_col`.

```py
def cofactor(A):
    """
    Calculate cofactor matrix of A
    """
    sel_rows = np.ones(A.shape[0],dtype=bool)
    sel_columns = np.ones(A.shape[1],dtype=bool)
    CO = np.zeros_like(A)
    sgn_row = 1
    for row in range(A.shape[0]):
        # Unselect current row
        sel_rows[row] = False
        sgn_col = 1
        for col in range(A.shape[1]):
            # Unselect current column
            sel_columns[col] = False
            # Extract submatrix
            MATij = A[sel_rows][:,sel_columns]
            CO[row,col] = sgn_row*sgn_col*np.linalg.det(MATij)
            # Reselect current column
            sel_columns[col] = True
            sgn_col = -sgn_col
        sel_rows[row] = True
        # Reselect current row
        sgn_row = -sgn_row
    return CO

def adjugate(A):
    """
    Calculate adjugate matrix of A
    """
    return cofactor(A).T
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1,3,5],[-2,-4,-5],[3,6,1]] , dtype = 'int')
m = np.linalg.det(x)
c =[[i for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        c[i][j] = (-1)*(i+j)*m
```

Comment: when i add c.T to the last line to transpose the matrix to get the final ans, it give the error 'List' object has no attribute 'T'

Comment: and the expected output is a 3 by 3 matrix

Answer (score 0):

The `c.T` to work without any errors, the array `c` should be a numpy array. Here the array `c` that @TaohidulIslam  declared is a Python List. So you are getting an error.

Declare `c` as follows:
`c =np.array([[i for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)])`

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the adjugate matrix by the transposal of the cofactor matrix
with the method below which is suitable for non singular matrices.
First, find the cofactor matrix, as follows:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-find-cofactor-of-a-matrix-using-numpy/
Then, find the transposal of the cofactor matrix.

```
import numpy as np
import math as mth

# get cofactors matrix 
def getcofat(x):
    eps = 1e-6
    detx = np.linalg.det(x)
    if (mth.fabs(detx) < eps):
        print("No possible to get cofactors for singular matrix with this method")
        x = None
        return x
    invx = np.linalg.pinv(x)
    invxT = invx.T
    x = invxT * detx
    return x
# get adj matrix
def getadj(x):
    eps = 1e-6
    detx = np.linalg.det(x)
    if (mth.fabs(detx) < eps):
        print("No possible to get adj matrix for singular matrix with this method")
        adjx = None
        return adjx
    cofatx = getcofat(x)
    adjx = cofatx.T
    return adjx

A = np.array([[1, 3, 5], [-2, -4, -5], [3, 6, 1]])
print(A)
print(np.linalg.det(A))
Acofat = getcofat(A)
print(Acofat)
Aadj = getadj(A)
print(Aadj)
```